# PHPunit for my UserController is not covering all lines

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms

Symfony project PHPunit coverage test

UserController

```
public function userEdit($id, Request $request)
    {

        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneByCode($id);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new Exception("User not found!");
        }

        $userForm = $this->createForm(UserForm::class, $user);
        $userForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userForm->isSubmitted() && $userForm->isValid()) {
            $this->userService->save($user);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'user/user.html.twig', [
            'form' => $userForm->createView(),
            ]
        );
    }
```

TestUserController

```
public function testUserEdit()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/test/edit');

        $formData = array(
            'username' => 'test',
            'email' => 'test@test.nl',
            'roles' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        );

        $this->assertEquals(
            200,
            $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
        );


        $form = $this->factory->create(UserForm::class);
        $object = User::fromArray($formData);

        $form->submit($formData);
        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }

    }
```

In the userEdit method we have a if loop. But When we run PHPunit coverage test the if loop is not executed. The other if loop for submit is also not covered.

What goes wrong and what can I do in order to cover the test ? Also is this the best solution for Symfony form test since I am new to PHPunit.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few things in your code that seem wrong:

The `userEdit` method name should be `userEditAction`.

Select the form like this:
`$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();`

That 'submit' text is the label on the submit button (e.g. Save).
And then, after filling the fields:
`$crawler = $client->submit($form);`

You check if the submit was successful by asserting that the resulting HTML page contains expected element (e.g.):

`$this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('h1')->count());`

Btw. put: `$client->followRedirects(true);` after instantiating the Client.

Examples are from the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/testing.html).

Regarding the some lines that were not covered by test: whenever you have `if` clause, you need to test for both conditions. In your case, first you probably have a valid user, instance of `User` and the other case should be that you pass there an invalid user (null or whatever else). That is usually accomplished by using `@dataProvider` annotation and method. The data provider method supplies sets of data to the test method. There can be more than one set, so another set contains invalid data to cover the other outcome of the `if()` clause.

This [blog](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-2-assertions-writing-a-useful-test-and-dataprovider/) has great examples.

Answer (score 0):

To cover the content of the if-conditions you have to fulfill the conditions new tests. To enter the first if for example you have to write a test where you mock the `userRepository` and make `findOneByCode` return null. Then the following if-condition will be executed and throw an exception. Finally you test for a thrown exception in the test.
For the other if-condition you proceed in a similar manner. Write a new test which is designed to fulfill the condition and test the code inside it.

Comment: I do not think that this is the method since the Symfony documentation shows a example.

Comment: My mistake. Apparently you are trying functional tests not unit tests. For the first if condition you can try to simply provide a false id. It should not be found by the repository and throw an exception.